# Increasing the float precision for plotting Mandelbrot fractal using GPU

Tags: python, floating-point, precision, numba, mandelbrot

I have written a program in python to plot the Mandelbrot set using pygame, multithreading and numba. Unfortunately, I can't zoom more than 1e-15 because of the limit of floats precision. When I do it become all pixelated. I heard about the decimal library that is more precise but it is not supported by numba.

Is there a way to represent very precise float simply enough to works with numba?

Edit : Forgot to mention it but I'm using double and tried using numpy longdouble but it doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: Can you use `double` precision type? In C I can do a doubling 2x zoom of more than 50 steps before losing definition. The single precision `float` type is all but useless for this task. But as an interpreted language, python isn't the best choice for serious M-set manipulation, which can require billions of arithmetic operations to create one image.

Comment: Forgot to mention it but yes, I'm using double and tried using numpy longdouble but ut doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: Perhpas the gpu is the limitation then.

Comment: you do not need a better precision to zoom. You can just apply some math tricks. The mandelbrot set is [self-similar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-similarity) so you can renormalize the values. Moreover, note that using double precision is very slow on mainstream GPUs.

Comment: Biloba "Is there a way to represent very precise float ..." --> How precise do you want?  1e-15 sounds precise for most folks.

Comment: @JérômeRichard not to mention that floats are just integers with a scale factor. You can just remove the DC offset and do integer math to whatever precision you want

Comment: @JérômeRichard can you give me a link or a reference to those math tricks ?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I would like to be able to go as far as I want, but I think I will go there easier with said math tricks

Comment: @MadPhysicist I really don't have the same idea of float representation. From what I understand, floats have an integer part and a decimal part. The decimal part is an addition of fraction. [Link to the wikipedia scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#/media/File:Float_example.svg)

Comment: @Biloba All common floating point values are some limited integer time a power of 2, not "integer part and a decimal part".  Nothing decimal about them.

Comment: Sorry, but I think @JérômeRichard is mistaken here. The Mandelbrot set is not perfectly self-similar in the way that something like the Koch curve is (e.g., via linear affine transformations), and you _do_ need better precision to zoom beyond a certain point. If there are mathematical tricks that remove that need, then those mathematical tricks don't seem to be known to the experts. See for example: https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2011/08/13/faster-fractals-through-algebra/

Comment: @MarkDickinson agreed, but with the **Julia set** if you have previously visited the *exact* location, then the iteration continues as before (because *c* is constant across the plane). I tried an implementation where if a *pixel* (encountered on the orbit) had been previously calculated I would simply add its depth to the current depth count, and stop the iteration. Of course, the actual coordinates were not exact, so it was very fast but not all that accurate.